# Send SQL data to new created stack

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-swarm

I have a problem with my docker microservice architecture and different approaches to solve this problems. I hope you can help me with your input.

**The question**: what is the best way to extract the data from the controllerDB and send this to the stack at creation time?

Given this architecture:

**controllerService:**

Connected to a docker socket to create stacks by a given compose file. Implemented in python 3.7 and pydocker.

**controllerDB:**

Data for the new stacks. MySQL database

**The problem**: every created stack needs a different subset of data from the database. The table which stores the data has columns don´t needed by the stack. This columns only indicate that this data are already used by a stack.

**The approaches**

1. create a mysql dump and send this to the mysql initdb folder.
2. create a docker config file by a python function and add it to the stack
3. send the data directly from controllerDB to stackDB
4. some other approach I don't see

**Ideas**

1. Is it possible to dump a database by a SQL query? I only know that a can select the dumping rows by the `--where=` option of `mysqldump` but not way to exclude columns.
2. controllerService send a query to controllerDB. This dataset is created into a config file and send to the stack. The Service hast to insert it to the database by its own.
3. I don't know if this is possible.

Regards
MarLei